# OneLogin one.saml.properties file

Tags: file, properties, saml, x509, onelogin

I am trying to generate the SP metadata by using the one.saml.properties file.

How do i specify the cert?

```
onelogin.saml2.sp.x509cert = -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIEtDCCBFe........
```

or

```
onelogin.saml2.sp.x509cert = MIIEtDCCBFegAwIBAgIEVF......
```

or should I just point to a file

```
onelogin.saml2.sp.x509cert= "absolute file path/certs.pem"
```

None of these options work. It throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.onelogin.saml2.exception.SettingsException: Invalid settings: sp_cert_not_found_and_required
at com.onelogin.saml2.Auth.<init>(Auth.java:224)
at com.onelogin.saml2.Auth.<init>(Auth.java:164)
at com.ibm.sp.Spgenerator.main(Spgenerator.java:49)
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your first example is the space between the header and the certificate bits. Instead of -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIEtDCCBFe.. it needs to be -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----MIIEtDCCBFe... Also do not put a space between the end of the bits and the footer, i.e. ...aFehqj-----END CERTIFICATE-----

See this file for a complete working example: https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/blob/90960e24684b450fb4477be1e4191cd0c3e9329d/core/src/test/resources/config/config.mywithnocert.properties

Comment: You can use this tool to properly format your certificate:
https://www.samltool.com/format_x509cert.php